# css altering width of inline child divs

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I am working on building a project where the child divs each individually have the full-width of the container, display inline, much like an inline navigation menu. Each individual child element has a width containing the full extent of the parent, however only one element at a time is shown. I have completed this, but have completed it in a way which is highly inefficient, I used an empty space html character to achieve the effect.

```
    Here is the code I have used:


  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>

            <style type="text/css">

                .parent > div{
                    display: inline;                
                }

                /*all child divs are displayed inline */

                .parent{
                    width:20%;  
                    position: relative;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    border:solid;
                }
                /* The parent container is going to be part of a dynamic jquery carousel so I have given the width a percentage
                */
                /*width does not apply to inline elements*/

                .children{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                /*class to specify attributes shared by all the child divs of the parent container*/

                .child-1{
                    background-color: #8A2BE2;
                }

                /*First child div*/

                .child-2{
                    left:100%;
                    background-color: #FF7F50;
                }

                /*second child div*/

            </style>

        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="main-parent">
                <div class="parent">
                    <div class="children child-1">
                        First child 
                    </div>

                    <div class="children child-2">
                        Second child
                    </div>
                    &nbsp;
                </div>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The menu items don't necessarily need to stay 'in line' since you are showing them one at a time anyway.

It's easiest if you follow an approach like this - all the navigation items are block full width elements, and you setup the height of the wrapper to be equal to a single nav item, and via javascript you play with the vertical positioning such that the one that you want comes into view (rather than play with the left variable of an absolute positioned element).

I think that if it's difficult for you to explain a concept, it will be probably even more difficult for a user to use your solution, so maybe a trip to the drawing board and see what details might be missing would do you good.